# How to write a cross-platform program?

Tags: cross-platform

I searched for some literature about cross-platform programing development and I didn't find something really good.

I'm not looking for a Virtual Machine for cross-platforming like Java does.

**Is there any book or literature about this?**

Comment: How do you define cross-platform? For example, ANSI C programs can be compiled on many platforms.

Comment: What sort of features does your program need? What platforms do you want to support? If you rely on features specified in POSIX, your program will be portable to many unices, but may not compile on Windows - at least, it probably won't unless you rely on the subset of POSIX that windows supports. Another way to make your program portable is to rely on an abstraction layer that takes care of the platform specific things for you, like Qt's network and thread facilities. The problem with that approach is your program will at best be portable to the systems supported by your abstraction layer.

Comment: For example, a program that uses a socket. It has different implementations in Linux or Windows.

Comment: It's not possible, true XPlatform apps will come when web OS (chorme os) will become a reality.

Comment: @So Many Questions - sockets are a bad example.  The sockets API is pretty much standardized with Berkley sockets on both UNIX and Windows.

Comment: I know sockets has similar API in different OS's. I referred sockets because the include's are different. How can solve it?

Comment: So Many Questions: It's not only the includes that are different, but also other details such as the types of arguments etc. You can solve that by using ifdefs, or by using a high level library. If you use C++ you can use [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) for example.

Comment: you can't get true cross platforming without some abstraction layer, Java, Erlang, Smalltalk and others user a Virtual Machine, some other languages call the same thing a "runtime", but in the end they all have at least 1 abstraction layer between the code and native OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Staffan and others have given sterling advice, so I am not going to offer a solution - just suggest an approach.

There are many possible solutions and I would say a major decision is whether or not you want a GUI. If not, you can probably go with C. With a GUI, go with Java (which you dion't want to), or use NetBEans as your IDE with Qt for the widgets.

But whatever you do, I think the most important is to detect potential pronlems as early as possible.  If you use C, you can use [Splint](http://www.splint.org/) or other static code analysis tools they will warn of portability issues. Similarly, turnning your compiler warning levels to max should help.

Set up a continuous integration system like Hudson to build everything regularly and make sure that you have lots of autometd unit tests (using CppUnit or similar) and use the same test on each platform, with the tests targetting portability issues.

Perhaps consider [Posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) or using only Ansi C or some other standards compliant language.

How you go about setting up CI depends on how many potential targets you have. Maybe you need to run each on a sepearte PC or in a sparate VM. If you chose C or C++ you might be happy with using GCC under Cygwin in Windows and the C/C++ compiler of your choice (need advice on a good free one?)

See also:

http://www.hookatooka.com/wpc/

and, of course, 
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-sg&q=portable+code

Comment: Almost ten years later, I recommend [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/). Have you tried it? I imagine that the platforms now are different from those of 10 years ago :-)

Answer (score 7):

I'd say that this boils down to:

- Not using non-standard "standard library" features, where non-standard depends on what platforms you target (e.g. POSIX-compatible systems). For example, if you use C don't use `popen()` if you want your application to run on non-POSIX systems.
- Make sure you handle endianess correctly where it needs to be, e.g. when you transmit data over the network to another computer possibly using a different byte order.
- Write only compliant code, e.g. don't depend on GCC/VC/name-your-compiler specific features.

On a more practical level my advice is:

- Use cross platform libraries that abstract the non-standard functionality you need, or write your code to handle all the platforms that you target.
- And, related to the point above, stay away from non-cross platform dependencies. E.g. use OpenGL instead of Direct3D, and Qt/Gtk/whatever instead of your platforms native widget toolkit.

EDIT: There's more stuff to think about, like not assuming that `/` is used as the path separator, or making invalid assumptions about which characters are allowed in file names.

Answer (score 3):

I asked for a book, but nobody referred it.

I found a book named "Cross-Platform Development in C++: Building Mac OS X, Linux, and Windows Applications".

There's goes a link for Amazon and a description for who are interested:

http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/032124642X/

```
   Cross-Platform Development in C++ is the definitive guide to developing 
   portable C/C++ application code that will run natively on Windows, 
   Macintosh, and Linux/Unix platforms without compromising functionality, 
   usability, or quality. 

   Long-time Mozilla and Netscape developer Syd Logan systematically 
   addresses all the technical and management challenges associated with 
   software portability from planning and design through coding, testing, 
   and deployment. Drawing on his extensive experience with cross-platform 
   development, Logan thoroughly covers issues ranging from the use of 
   native APIs to the latest strategies for portable GUI development. Along 
   the way, he demonstrates how to achieve feature parity while avoiding 
   the problems inherent to traditional cross-platform development 
   approaches. 

   This book will be an indispensable resource for every software 
   professional and technical manager who is building new cross-platform 
   software, porting existing C/C++ software, or planning software that may 
   someday require cross-platform support. 

   Build Cross-Platform Applications without Compromise

   Throughout the book, Logan illuminates his techniques with realistic 
   scenarios and extensive, downloadable code examples, including a 
   complete cross-platform GUI toolkit based on Mozilla's XUL that you can 
   download, modify, and learn from. Coverage includes 
     - Policies and procedures used by Netscape, enabling them to ship Web 
   browsers to millions of users on Windows, Mac OS, and Linux 
     - Delivering functionality and interfaces that are consistent on all 
   platforms 
     - Understanding key similarities and differences among leading 
   platform-specific GUI APIs, including Win32/.NET, Cocoa, and Gtk+ 
     - Determining when and when not to use native IDEs and how to limit 
   their impact on portability 
     - Leveraging standards-based APIs, including POSIX and STL
     - Avoiding hidden portability pitfalls associated with floating point, 
   char types, data serialization, and types in C++ 
     - Utilizing platform abstraction libraries such as the Netscape 
   Portable Runtime (NSPR) 
     - Establishing an effective cross-platform bug reporting and tracking 
   system 
     - Creating builds for multiple platforms and detecting build failures 
   across platforms when they occur 
     - Understanding the native runtime environment and its impact on 
   installation 
     - Utilizing wxWidgets to create multi-platform GUI applications from a 
   single code base 
     - Thoroughly testing application portability
     - Understanding cross-platform GUI toolkit design with Trixul
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use a "code once, run anywhere" development environment (in other words, some of your code has to be customized for each platform being targeted), then make sure you really need your program to run on multiple platforms.

I know of a program that compiled into two versions, one for Mac and one for Windows.  Although most of the code was identical for either platform, a portion was specific to the host O/S, and frequently needed modifications and testing unique to the two environments.  Sales were 98% Windows, 2% Mac, yet the two versions essentially required equal design/programming/testing/documentation time.  The owners decided that instead of giving half of each $ of future programmer time to the Mac version for only a 2% return, they simply canned that version.  Their cross-platform issues immediately disappeared, and the productivity of their programmers essentially doubled (which pleased the Windows customers).

Answer (score 1):

Without using a Virtual Machine you encounter always the same problem: many features that you can use on an operating system are specific for that operating system.

This because noone never seriously cared about defining just a way to do the same things, mainly because having DirectX10 for example is an advantage over other operating systems.

I would say that is rather easy to write a cross-platform application able to run on MacosX and Linux just because you can take advantage of many things that are able to run on both machines (think about X11 or GTK) and both of them have Unix under the hood. Usually with some effort you can manage to make your programs work also under Windows (maybe with MinGW or Cygwin) also if compatibility of some features is missing.

In addition the different operating systems have effectively different implementations for same things (think about sockets, io system, graphics, audio, etc) so this makes impossible to write just a version that works everywhere: you are forced to write a different version for any OS you plan to release your program for.

The short answer is: no, you can't without a VM language unless you restrict your program capabilities to a small set of common features.

(I'm assuming we're talking about C/C++ just because usually other languages are managed by just one group of people each that takes care about releasing it as much cross-platform as possible)

I don't really see any real bad point on relying on a Virtual Machine. Computer nowadays are able to run VMs without big speed issues. Then having something that cares about placing an abstraction layer between you and the OS will let you to do advanced things by just knowing one way to do it.. I think that a speed tradeoff of something like Java is widely acceptable.. they just did what you would have to do when trying to write a complex cross-platform application.

Just a fact: I really got into pain when trying to port a virtual machine I wrote from Unix (Linux / OSX ) to Windows because of `freopen` function.. unfortunately Windows manages streams in a different way compared to other OSs so MinGW lacked that function and I had to find a way around that problem..

Comment: @Jack - that isn't quite true.  Using conditional compilation in C or C++, you can write a program that will use OS-specific features and simply compile differently on each platform.  Of course in that case the effort can almost be the same as writing two applications.

Comment: Yes, but that's not writing a cross-platform application. That's writing two different application that relies on some shared (cross-platform) components that don't use advanced features. Conditional compiling is a way to compile on many platforms without having a real cross-platform program (since as you state too the effort is almost as much as writing 2 applications)

Comment: There are many open-source programs that compile on Windows and various unix OSes, for example, so, by using autoconf, for example, you can have the environment adapt so that it can compile on just about any OS/hardware combination.

Comment: @Jack: You seem to be unaware of -- or choose to ignore -- languages and toolkits like tcl/tk and python/wxPython (among others) that do a great job of abstracting away the OS and windowing system. You can do a great many things with these languages in a cross-platform way, without resorting to a small set of common features.

Comment: @Bryan: I don't ignore them, I just think they are a compromise (without digging if good or bad one) that is of the same magnitude of a Virtual Machine. Then GUIs are a semi-advanced feature, you can find plenty of cross-platform way to build a GUI but it's not a general answer. The general answer is that you can't do it without searching for specific cross-platform components for every advanced feature you need, that is like building your own virtual machine :)

Comment: @Jack: With your definition there is NO cross-platform program. For example, I can invent a theoretical Turning complete machine that no available compilers target. A more reasonable, albeit somewhat vague, definition of cross-platform is that it runs on most platforms. What "most" means depends but for many it means "runs on *nix, Windows and OS X". Perhaps more accurate is to say that a program is cross-platform if it runs on more than one platform.

Answer (score 1):

There is no certain Virtual machine of Java that works on different platforms. Java has different virtual machines that run on different platforms in order for a Java program to run on each platform. It is kind of a layer which makes the Java programs be able to run everywhere.

For instance a C program can run on both windows and linux but it should be compiled with the corresponding compiler of the OS on which you run the application.

But in java, you don't need to do so. You just compile the source and can distribute the compiled files which are ready to be executed on any platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose a modern scripting language (Tcl and Python are two sterling examples) you can write programs that run almost identically on all platforms. Sure, you'll have to make small allowances for one platform or another, but that's pretty easy to do. Take a look at those languages for some inspiration.

You won't create the next photoshop or first person shooter with these languages, but for the vast majority of common programming tasks these are quite suitable.

If you want something concrete, take a look at http://tkdocs.com which showcases the Tk toolkit running on multiple platforms and with multiple languages (Tcl, Ruby, Perl, Python)

Comment: Actually you can right the next Photoshop in mostly Python and some portable C extensions for performance, about 80% of Adobe Lightroom and all its plug ins are written in Lua. And Google has a version of Quake running in JavaScript @ 30+ fps.